# Converges to 0 vs. Diverges to 0; Terminology in p-adic Analysis

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

In practice, in p-adic analysis, when referring to a sequence of numbers it is common to use the terminology "converges to 0". However, isn't this terminology, technically, incorrect by the definition of the p-adic order since we extend the domain of the p-adic order to 0 by defining v(0)=∞ so that |0|=0? In consideration of the definition of the p-adic norm, |x|=p^(-v(x)), should the correct terminology not be, in fact, "diverges to 0", analogous to the notion of an infinite product diverging to 0 (*inversely*, of course)?

I admit that I may be nitpicking here, and it is very possible that I am simply incorrect or overthinking. But, this terminology does imply subtle differences. In particular, while in real analysis, it is very natural to define an elementary function by a sum or product, in p-adic analysis, the terminology seems to suggest that it is more natural to define an elementary function by a product, for example, the Artin-Hasse exponential function.

EDIT:
I would like to point out, before others do, that we also technically extend the real absolute value by defining |0|=0 also. However, this actually reinforces my original post rather than contradicting it. What this says, or at least, what I infer from this, is that it is technically always more correct to use the terminology "diverges to 0" as opposed to "converges to 0". It is only in the real case, in other words, the case for the p-adic absolute value || for arbitrary p, under the limit as p approaches the least infinite ordinal, that the distinction between the two notions becomes ambiguous. The ambiguity arises because the real line is connected, so that, in special circumstances like the one considered (where the extension is in the topological boundary of the domain), extension of the domain of definition of a function becomes continuation, while restricting our consideration to only positive numbers in the domain, the absolute value becomes the identity map.

EDIT 2:
I expected this to be obvious from the question, but do note that the question is in fact a question of consistency. Although, at face value it may appear to be somewhat shallow, it is actually *very* deep, in the sense that it has very deep consequences for an individual's conceptualization of the p-adic numbers, and in particular how the aforementioned individual uses them as a mathematical tool.

I do apologize for not writing in latex, by the way, I currently only have my surface with me, and doing so on it is an extremely tedious task.

Comment: By your lights, is it licit to speak of the sequence $\{1+p^n\}$ converging to $1$?

Comment: Yes, of course. |1-(1+p^n)|=|p^n|=p^(-n) approaches 0 after applying the limit

Answer (score 1):

For convergence, we need a topology, here obtained from a metric, here obtained from a norm, here defined in terms of the order: $|x|_p=\begin{cases}p^{-v(x)}&x\ne0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$. After this, convergence has its standard meaning from topology and $0$ is really "very near" to $p^{1000}$.

Comment: I understand this. I think you completely missed the point...

Comment: I elaborated on my original post to clarify the point that I'm trying to make here.

Comment: To address your answer explicitly, you're right the notions of convergence and divergence follow from the definition of metric. Not the other way around. I admit the way my post was originally written may have caused you to infer that I did not understand this, so, I modified it appropriately. However, convergence and divergence are terms applied to sequences, not numbers. I'm sure you knew this. But, the informal notion of "very near" does not always coincide with the formal definition convergence, as in the case with infinite products. This was my point.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is the problem here. Let's consider the general approach with the following definition.

**Definition A:** A sequence $(x_n)_n$ of elements in a topological space $X$ is *convergent to $y$* ($y\in X$) if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $y$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in U$ whenever $n\geq N$.

In $\mathbb{Q}_p$, a neighbourhood of $0$ can be defined in terms of the absolute value $|\cdot|_p:\mathbb{Q}_p\to\mathbb{R}$ or the valuation $v:\mathbb{Q}_p\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$, in other words, these two functions induce the same topology on $\mathbb{Q}_p$. These two functions are related by the identity $$|x|_p=e^{-v(x)}$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ (using the convention $0=e^{-\infty}$ if you like). Therefore, a basic neighborhood of $0$ can be written in two different ways:
$$U_r:=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}_p:|x|_p<e^{-r}\}=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}_p:v(x)>r\}$$
for $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Notice that, the larger $r$ gets, the smaller the neighbourhood $U_r$ becomes.
Now, according the definition A, a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements in $\mathbb{Q}_p$  approach to $0$ when $|x_n|_p\to 0$, or equivalently, when $v(x_n)\to\infty$.
Here none of the expressions $|x_n|_p\to 0$, $v(x_n)\to\infty$ is the heart of the convergence of the sequence $(x_n)$ to $0$. Here, the important fact is that for every $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $x_n\in U_r$ for $n$ large enough.